# What is the difference between "new ArrayList<ClassName>()" and "new ArrayList<>()" when constructing an ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, constructor

Here's a concrete example:

```
  ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
```

Both ways seem to work fine. What is the difference?

Comment: None. It changed in java 8 I think.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9, Quote: "If the type argument list to the class is empty — the diamond form `<>` — the type arguments of the class are inferred."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Constructing:

```
new ArrayList<>();
```

You're telling the compiler to `Infer` the type from the left side.

Now:

```
new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is explicitly declaring the type you intend to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are no difference, I can call it new feature.

We had to specify the type argument before Java 7 :

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

From Java 7 we can just use Diamond :

```
ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the difference, Java's designers want to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right from my earlier programming classes, this is an example of a [syntactical sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) feature that was added in a newer version of java. Java infers yours type String when you instantiate y.